# Need to develop real time communication service to communicate between one website to another website

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I am developing an application which require cross domain communication from one website to another website. For example www.website1.com can send any message to www.website2.com and second website is able to receive command which is sent by website 1.

Please suggest me how can i achieve this case.

Comment: It seems u r very new to Web development area. You can simply achieve this using Web Services/WCF Services/Web Api etc. Configure them according to your reuirement

Comment: I need real time UI update. if website 1 is send any command on that time second website 2 UI should update automatically.

Comment: u can ping your after via ajax request after few seconds.

Comment: No i don't want ping any method at an interval. Need real time update!

Comment: Let mw know if u r looking for somthing like - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M

Comment: there are techniques there but this question doesn't belong to SO because it is too broad and opinion based